# Adding boolean flag to Angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I need to add an *active* class to first item that slipped through `ng-if="!item.hidden"` loop. It works fine at first as *$first* directive means *0* index. But Let say the `0 to 3rd` indexes is hidden therefore wont be displayed, and 4th index is the first to be displayed.

Here's my actual code

```
<div ng-if="!item.hidden" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.event.items">    
<div class="title item" ng-class="{'active': $first }">
```

`$first` directive doesn't  work when the index I am applying active class is not *0*.

Answer (score 1):

In place of ng-if condition you can filter the items.
after that $first return index 0 by default

```
<div  ng-repeat="item in items| filter:{hidden:false}">    
<div class="title item" ng-class="{'active': $first }">
  {{item.value}}
  </div>
```

Please check working plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/mFVhkf55bvv8Z70F9ufk?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

It was a good question, the problem as you mentioned, it cannot be done by **`$index`** as **`$index`** will even get counted if it the element is hidden.

But, angular is more and more powerful and it has many more alternatives.

Here is a solution from them,

In this answer I used `filter` to directly filter the values from the array so that, only the filtered objects will be displayed.

**`ng-repeat="x in records | filter: (x.hidden == true)"`**

**what the above lines make is, it will not take into consideration, the values where hidden is true.**

**so, the `$index` will not start from '0'**

Here is the working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">



<table ng-controller="myCtrl" border="1">
<tr  ng-class="{'active': $index == 0 }"  ng-repeat="x in records | filter: (x.hidden == true)">
 
  <td>{{x.Name}}</td>
  <td>{{x.Country}}</td>  
</tr>
</table>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.records = [
    {
      "Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
      "Country" : "Germany",
      "hidden": true
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Berglunds snabbköp",
      "Country" : "Sweden",
      "hidden": false
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
      "Country" : "Mexico",
      "hidden": false
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Ernst Handel",
      "Country" : "Austria",
      "hidden": false
    }
  ]
});
</script>

</body>
<style>
.active
{
background: green;
}
<style>
</html>
```

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/yZTeu9qXrK30bob1vUXt?p=preview)